# download only new files from ftp using WGET/cUrl

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, wget, curl

i have Windows 2008 Server on which i store DB backups on daily basis. I want to be able to download new files only using wget, curl or windows built-in FTP doesn't matter.

Can you help me with command? I need only new files, ones that exists on local machine (Windows Vista) and server should be skipped.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the **--noclobber** option for wget. Also, if you have [`ncftpget`](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpget.html) available, I believe it skips existing files by default.

Answer (score 4):

What you are actually looking for is --timestamping. 
--no-clobber just wont download existing files taking no concideration if the files on the server are newer or not.

--timestamping looks at the file to see if the version remote is newer than local before downloading.

Answer (score 2):

With wget:
New = doesn't exist OR more recently modified

Each time run: (probably won't work on existing files - you need the initial download to contain the remote timestamp)
wget --timestamping -r ftp://yoursite.com/path/

https://superuser.com/questions/283481/how-do-i-properly-set-wget-to-download-only-new-files

With cURL you can use the -z option to specify that only files after a certain date should be downloaded

curl -z "Jun 30 2011" http://yoursite.com/file.html

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html